# Reordering ListView items in UWP messes up the content

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm using ListViews to make a kanban list in UWP. As the picture below shows, re-ordering items a few times results in the content of one or some of them being wrong.
Further re-ordering will have the content going back and forth being correct and wrong and everything is back to normal when re-loading the page which means there's not data change but just the image control displaying the wrong image. ( It can happen with any other control too )

For reference, The images are local files which I'm loading in the Image control's Loaded event, and the ListView simply has CanReorderItems and AllowDrop set to true.

[image]

Here's how the XAML looks

```
 <ListView x:Name="LView"  MinWidth="240" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind List.Tasks}"  ReorderMode="Enabled" CanReorderItems="True" AllowDrop="True" CanDragItems="True" SelectionMode="None"  IsItemClickEnabled="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled="True" ItemClick="LView_ItemClick">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
          ...
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="mongo:Task">
                <Grid Padding="12 0" >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        ...
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                    <Border CornerRadius="4 4 0 0" Margin="-12 0" >
                        <Image x:Name="Cover" MaxHeight="160" Stretch="UniformToFill" Tag="{x:Bind Attachments}" Loaded="Image_Loaded" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                    </Border>
```

...

And here's the Loaded event

```
private async void Image_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var img = sender as Image;
    
    if (img.Source is object) return;

    var attachments = img.Tag as ObservableCollection<TaskAttachment>;
    if (attachments is null) return;
    var cover = attachments.Where(_a => _a.is_cover).FirstOrDefault();

    if (cover is object && cover.type == "image")
    {
        var path = BrandboxSettings.Instance.server_path + "projects\\" + cover.path;
        Output.WriteLine(path);
        var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path);
        
        using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            // Set the image source to the selected bitmap
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

            await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
            img.Source = bitmapImage;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: It's worth noting that even if one of the cards does not initially have an image, reordering will cause it to have one.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Sounds like ListView item virtualization / recycling. I suspect that the image provided as sender has been recycled from another listview item and therefore already has it's `Source` property set.
Have you tried removing the `if (img.Source is object) return;` to see if it resolves the issue? If it does, there are probably more robust ways of resolving the issue but this should at least show if it is the issue.

Comment: I can confirm it's recycling actually as I have a chat list view and at some point new added items have the text from old ones until I reload.
And that if statement wasn't there initially so it's not the issue

Comment: So did removing the above line resolve the issue?

Comment: No it did not but I actually think I found a solution.
I changed the ItemsPanel to a StackPanel and it seems to be working now

Comment: Ah, it's probably because the Loaded event probably won't be getting fired for a recycled item. What was your solution?

Comment: My bad I edited the comment and posted it. I have the habit of pressing enter for line breaks but that posts the comment here haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I tried changing the ItemsPanel to a StackPanel and it seems to be working now.

```
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizationStackPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

Edit:
It also seems to work by setting the Panel to VirtualizationStackPanel

Comment: Per my comments above, the issue was related to virtualization which is very important if you are displaying significant numbers of items in your list view. If not then this solution is fine but otherwise you might want to consider changing your strategy for loading the image.

Comment: What do you think is a good idea for loading an image inside DataTemplate? I can't just bind the path as the image is a local file and is not located inside the app's folder